# Excel, check if 2 values match in 2 columns in a table and return another value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to produce a simplified set of data in a secondary worksheet from a very large table by matching 2 values with 2 columns. These values repeat multiple times in each column, I'm looking to find when they BOTH match. For example:

```
++++|---A---|---B---|---C---|
1---|  Sup  |       |       |
2---|       |   D   |       |
3---|  Sup  |   D   | Value | <<< This is the row I want to extract "C" from
```

My current formulas for obtaining the COLUMN and ROWS. The table is effectively a LARGE roster with dates as the columns after a few 'descriptor' columns. The column which contains 'Sup' is the role (where Sup = Supervisor). I'm trying to use functions to dynamically identify the supervisor on day shift (D) for the day.

First Row for "D"

```
=MATCH("D", MASTER[B]), 0)
```

First Row for "Sup"

```
=MATCH("Sup", MASTER[A], 0)
```

I can't tell easily when they match up as there are 7-8 Supervisors in the roster with only 1 ever being on day shift.

Any clues? Cheers!

P.S. I cannot use Macros or VB for this as it's locked down by group policy!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match both "D" and "Sup" in the same column.  What column heading distinguishes the columns you have labeled "--A--" and "--B--"?

Comment: Apologies Bandersnatch, that's me being lazy and copy pasting things without appropriately editing them, I've updated them accordingly.

Comment: When they both match what?  You say they repeat in each column.  Are you comparing to an earlier entry in the same column or simply the presence of a value in both A and B?  Just the first case where this happens or every case?

Comment: Hey fixer1234, I've added some additional context in the edit for clarification.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure I understand the question, but if you're looking for the row that contains `Sup` in col A and `D` in col B, a simple solution is to add a helper column that contains the concatenation of A&B.  Then MATCH `SupD` (target) in the helper column.

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do it for you:

```
=if(A1="D",if(B1="Sup",C1,"Not Matched"),"Not Matched")
```

You could put the above in D1 and copy it down.
Column D will then contain the value of column C when A=D and B=Sup.